# how to read or convert a value of input type of time in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, html, date

I have a input filed with type = "time". I want to read hours and minutes on controller side or I want to convert it to Date.

Here is the input field

```
<input type="text" name="eventStartTime" ng-bind-type="date" 
ng-model="vm.event.eventStartTime"
ng-required="true"
onfocus="this.type='time'; this.setAttribute('onfocus','');this.blur();this.focus();"
placeholder="Event Start Time">
```

On controller if i try to convert it to Date format i am receiving value as invalid date.

Here is the code I am trying

```
 console.log(new Date(vm.event.eventStartTime));
```

If there is a way to convert it directly to date it's awesome. Otherwise i am looking for the way to get hours and minutes separately and i will create new date with it.